# How do I get a file path using a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm trying to create a button to get a file directory using `tkinter`. I get the button to pop up and the function I created works. The problem is when the function returns the value, I get ".!button" or ".!button1" instead of the file directory.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("100x100")

def getFolderPath():
  return filedialog.askdirectory()

btnFind = ttk.Button(gui, text="Open Folder",command=getFolderPath)
btnFind.grid(row=0,column=2)
print(btnFind) 
gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `print(btnFind)` does not print the return value of the function bound to the button press, it prints out the name of the button itself. In fact, returning something from the function isn't useful because you can't access the return value. It is better to create a global variable to store the selected folder, or, in this case, print it straight from the function:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("100x100")

def getFolderPath():
   print(filedialog.askdirectory())

btnFind = ttk.Button(gui, text="Open Folder",command=getFolderPath)
btnFind.grid(row=0,column=2)
gui.mainloop()
```

To store the value in a global variable use the `global` keyword:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("100x100")

folder = None  # Declare global variable first

def getFolderPath():
   global folder
   folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

btnFind = ttk.Button(gui, text="Open Folder",command=getFolderPath)
btnFind.grid(row=0,column=2)
gui.mainloop()
```

Here is an example of how you might use a global variable to store the folder, and then use it later:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("200x100")

folder = None

def getFolderPath():
    global folder
    folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

def onFolderConfirmed():
    global folder
    if folder is None:
        strvarError.set("Please select a folder first")
    else:
        doSomethingWithFolder()

def doSomethingWithFolder():
    ...  # Your code here

btnFind = ttk.Button(gui, text="Open Folder", command=getFolderPath)
btnFind.grid()
btnConfirm = ttk.Button(gui, text="Confirm Folder Choice", command=onFolderConfirmed)
btnConfirm.grid(row=1)
strvarError = StringVar()
lblError = Label(gui, textvar=strvarError)
lblError.grid(row=2)
gui.mainloop()
```

Here I added another button to confirm the choice of folder. If the user presses this without having selected a folder, it prompts them to select one; if not it executes some other code. If you wanted the other code to be run as soon as a folder is selected, just put that code straight in the `getFolderPath` function.

Comment: thank you, but is there way to use this value in this function cause returning seems to not work. And printing it does not help if i want to do something with the directory

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the value. If you want to create a new file there, say, then you can simply do that in the function. Alternatively, you can store the value in a global variable for later use.

Comment: thanks lecdi for helping so much, when i try this if i try to print the folder in the end right before gui.mainloop() , when i print i just get None instead of the file directory. It is most likely my fault due to the fact that i am new to the python can you help a bit more?  https://prnt.sc/26hj1sm

Comment: The problem is that the `print` function is called right at the start of the program before the button has been pressed, so the variable `folder` has not been set yet and is still `None`. If you want to use the global variable, you have to wait till the folder has been selected before using it. Maybe, there could be another button to confirm the choice of folder, and when that is clicked you use the global variable. In this case, you would need to check if it was `None` or not and tell the user to select a folder if it was `None`. (The idea is that it is `None` until the user selects a folder)

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by the print being in the start of the program, isnt the print in the end? https://prnt.sc/26hj1sm. One more thing the only way i can actually print this value is if i put it after the .mainloop which isnt convenient because i have to end the program for it to work? what do u say

Comment: to me it looks like the code is not waiting for the button to be executed which is kind of weird in my opinion it just keeps running while waiting for the button to complete

Comment: if i cant print the variable doesnt that mean i cant use it in the loop?

Comment: The button may not be at the start of the code, but all the code gets executed immediately at the start of the program. When `.mainloop()` is called, only then are the window and button shown and the user able to select a directory. So if you want to use the variable, it all has to be done in functions which are bound to tkinter widgets.

Comment: (This is because using functions bound to tkinter widgets is the only way to get code to execute while `.mainloop()` is still running - putting code directly before it will run before the window is even shown, and putting code after it will only run after the window is closed.)

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example of how to use the global variable, using a function bound to a new button I created.

Comment: Oops, I meant the print not the button in my comment three comments ago, but I can't edit it for some reason. Same principle anyway

Comment: Thank you so much! i have fixed it thank to you one thing for later purposes can you explain to me what these 2 lines do?
strvarError = StringVar()
lblError = Label(gui, textvar=strvarError)

Comment: `lblError = Label(gui, textvar=strvarError)` creates a label to show text in the window, and calls it `lblError`. The label should show a prompt asking the user to select a folder if they haven't already when they press the confirm button; this means the text of the label needs to change later to show the prompt. Therefore, a `StringVar` is used - it allows the text inside the label to be changed. So `strvarError = StringVar()` creates an empty `StringVar` which is changed inside the confirm button function if the user has not selected a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing button var...
Simply do:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk


gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("100x100")


def getFolderPath():
  file = filedialog.askdirectory()
  #do what you want with file

ttk.Button(gui, text="Open Folder",command=getFolderPath).grid(row=0,column=2)

 
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: after this the variable would be a local variable so i cant use it outside the funciton, is there a way to use the variable globally?

Comment: You can put before assigning variable file: global file

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.