# how to download a file from project directory in python

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a tkinter interface with a button that should download a specific pdf file which is stored in the project folder. I know ways to download files wit a url but in my case its the file that only exists in my local project directory. How can i implement this?

Comment: If the file is a local file, why do you need to use an URL? Just use the path of the file.

Comment: Maybe this link help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814115/how-do-i-get-a-file-path-using-a-button

Comment: i don't need to use a URL for the download. But all methods I find is all about this

Comment: the thing is when accessing a file on local filesystem, it's not called a download. See the dictionary reference for [download](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/download). What do you actually mean with *that should download a specific pdf file*?. What do you want to do with this PDF?